# How to close DHT-protocol links?

Tags: udp, bittorrent, deluge

I looked at the log on my router and I noted alert messages concerning UDP and internet addresses.

[image]

I decided to sniff the traffic (with wireshark) and highlighted DHT-protocol/UDP packets.
The links/sockets are between external addresses and my router.

[image]

My bittorent tool (Deluge on windows) is not active but these links are still established: in fact they never close.

Is it possible to kill/stop/cancel/desactivate these links because they overload the firewall of my router ?

Comment: this belongs on [superuser](https://superuser.com/), unless you want it answered in terms of technical background